# Copy PK Values into NULL Fields

Tags: sql

[image]

James speak three languages. I would like to copy the PK 3023 into Italy and Spanish rows using simple SQL query.

Sample rule applies to Liza.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Note that this is just manually typed report that shall be imported into Oracle

Comment: First suggestion that comes up is that the table should be normalized into two tables. and going further, it should be split to three tables. `Person, Languages and PersonLanguages`.

Comment: Please show the code that produced the above.  Was it SQL or a Report, or just what?   If it was SQL, then also please list the values in the table that it is FROM.

Comment: Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: After looking at your table image, it looks like it is prepared in Excel. If you have real table which is as same as your excel, can try following ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the comments are very correct, still I have prepared a solution keeping your current requirements as it is, answer is made in SQL Server, hope it helps you.

```
With CTE as 
(
select *
    ,Dense_Rank() over(order by UserId) as Rnk
 from UserLang
 ), CTE1 as
 (
 select  a.UserID as srcUID ,ab.UserID as destUID,a.userName as srcUName,ab.userName  as destUName from CTE as a
 outer apply
    (
        select top 1 * from CTE as b
        where a.seqID > b.seqID
            and b.userID is not null
        order by b.seqID desc
    )as ab
where a.userID is null
)
update CTE1 set srcUID = destUID ,srcUName = destUName
```

Link for **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b189e/1)**